# Android NDK-build process in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to get the sample app of [antidote](http://oss.signove.com/index.php/Antidote_port_to_Android_ICS) running ([source code](https://github.com/signove/antidote)).

I am confused as to how I need to run my app in Android Studio. I put the C-source files in the `/jni` folder, installed Cygwin and run the command `../android/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=app/src/main/` from in the `/myworkspace/myApp`-folder.

I don't seem to be getting any errors, and a `/libs` folder has been created with in it a library, as depicted in the image below.

[image: Tree of files]

However, when clicking the green run-button, Android Studio still gives errors in `:app:compileDebugNdk`. Since the code is compiled, does the ndk still need to be run? How do I turn this off? And do I still need to somehow install the library ndk-build has made?

This is my `build.gradle` for the project:

```
sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And this is the `build.gradle` for the Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.signove.health.service"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets.main{
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your _build.grade_?

Comment: @EduardoGomez: I've added my `build.gradle`.

Comment: Can you attach the build file for the app module? That should be sufficient to help out to configure the build with the elements provided by the Android plugin.

Comment: @EduardoGomez: My bad, updated my question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're disabling automatic ndk-build calls from sourceSets.main{ *jni.srcDirs = [ ]* } Then you may want to make Gradle plugin call it adding the *ndkBuild task*.

Check this answer out: [execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk' failed to run this command ndk-build.cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453085/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-failed-to-run-this-command-ndk)