# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'

Tags: android, eclipse

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>    Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>     Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
>      https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
>     Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
>      https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html

Comment: you have to install Cmake,ndk,LLB sdk in android studio

Comment: sailing already done but there is still the problem ?

Comment: i think there is some  error in your c++ code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453085/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-failed-to-run-this-command-ndk here is the answer of your question .

Answer (score 0):

Error:Execution failed for task ':libraryMaskLayout:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to parse XML resource file '/Users/machd/Documents/les codes /Game/Android Studio/fastbatterycharger/codecanyon-19571598-fast-battery-charger-5x-battery-saver-with-admob-ads-google-analytics-firebase-integration/FastChargerSorceCode/Code/FastChargerAdmob/libraryMaskLayout/build/intermediates/bundles/debug/res/values/values.xml'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsaRr.png)